# Trying to understand Bash logical testing that comes out the opposite way:

Tags: bash, shell-script

Why is this 0?

```
$ echo $(( 0 && 0 ))
0
```

Why is this 0?

```
$ echo $(( 1 && 0 ))
0
```

Why is this 0?

```
$ echo $(( 0 && 1 ))
0
```

Why is this 1?

```
$ echo $(( 1 && 1 ))
1
```

Comment: Why "opposite way"?

Answer (score 3):

This matches the definition of “[logical and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)”, which is what `&&` represents in an arithmetic context. The truth table is as follows:

```
  |  F  |  T
--+-----+-----
F |  F  |  F
--+-----+-----
T |  F  |  T
```

“A and B” is true only if both A and B are true.

In the shell’s arithmetic context, operators are [implemented as defined in the C standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02_01), where “true” is any non-zero value and “false” is zero. This is indeed the opposite of exit codes, where “true” (or rather, “success”) is zero and “false” (or rather, “error”) is any non-zero value.

See also:

```
$ echo $((2 && 2))
1

$ echo $((-1 && 2))
1
```

Comment: Another piece of the "comes out _the opposite way_" puzzle is that 0 is _false_ in an arithmetic context, while an _exit-status_ of 0 is _true_ in the context of the shell.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that’s where the confusion comes from! I missed that...

Answer (score 1):

`man $SHELL`

tells

```
&&     logical AND
```

So the rule is right side will be evaluated only if left side is TRUE. Since you are using the convention of 0 and 1. 0 is FALSE and 1 is TRUE.

Now lets discuss the code and then explanation.

```
echo $(( 0 && 0 ))
```

&& - will not evaluate the right side as left side is 0 and hence prints 0

```
$ echo $(( 1 && 0 ))
```

&& - will evaluate the right side as left side is 1 and sadly the right side is 0 and hence prints 0

```
echo $(( 0 && 1 ))
```

&& - will not evaluate the right side as the left side is 0 and hence prints 0

```
echo $(( 1 && 1 ))
```

&& - will evaluate the right side as the left side is 1 and hurray the right side is also 1 and hence prints 1.

**Edit**

As pointed by one user , the SHELL `&&` has a property of short-circuit (along with logical) . And point to be noted is logical not equivalent to short-circuit all the time.

Comment: Note that “logical and” doesn’t necessarily imply short-circuiting; it’s described as “logical” to distinguish it from “binary”. Making it short-circuiting is a separate concern, specified for the shell because its `&&` operator (along with other arithmetic operators) is specified as being equivalent to the corresponding C operator (see [the relevant section of POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_01_02_01)).

Comment: @Stephen Kitt ok . I got your point. SHELL `&& ` alone short-circuit. But generally  logical is not equivalent to short-circuit.

Comment: My point is that your answer says that “So the rule is right side will be evaluated only if left side is TRUE”, seemingly presenting that as a consequence of the fact that “&&” is “logical AND”, but it’s not a consequence of that.